# Android IntentService call

Tags: android, sockets, serversocket, intentservice, android-networking

I am trying to have a bidirectional connection between 2 devices, one will be the server and the other one the client. Since it is bidirectional, both can send a receive data.

I am creating them in an Activity that i have, that lists the installed apps that i have on my phone (filtered the system apps). Then i have an adapter for that list, where i define a listener for the items of that list. 
Basically if i press one of the items from the list, i want to send a message to the other device.

**So, if inside the method onHandleIntent() i am waiting for messages, where do I put the code to SEND messages ?**

EDIT: I could create another service for the send part but that would make me create 4 services, 2 for the client (send and receive) and another 2 for the server (send and receive again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IntentService has the following behavior:

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time.

from [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). The same IntentService isn't supposed to do 2 things at the same time- if it is listening (I guess a while loop in onHandleIntent?), then any messages you send to that IntentService while it is listening will not be handled. 
They will be queued until listening is done, and sent then.
You can either create two IntentServices (one for sending, one for receiving), or create a new Service that will spin up its own Threads which can send and listen concurrently.

I'd imagine that having send and receive be done by different Services would be easier.

Comment: Thank you a lot for you help ! I will follow your advice and use two different IntentService (to send and receive). Maybe one day i will check if having a Service with 2 threads would be more efficient or not. Again, huge thank you for the advice, i was kinda stuck. I am new here and i dont know if my votes will help you, but i hope they do :)

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but i think that there might be some problems with using two IntentServices (and stablishing the connection in the onStartCommand method - sockets and stream objects - ), since it will make me have two sets of sockets for the same two devices. I don't know if that will be problematic. So maybe one service with two threads inside would be better, because that way, you could use the same socket and stream objects.

Comment: I also had a Service that did some sort of concurrent reading/writing to a stream. What I did was have one Service (not IntentService) that spawns off a listening Thread on start, and kills it when stopped. Something like this may or may not work for you, but it made sense to me :)

Comment: Thank you Bob. Just to update what i wrote earlier : i tried using two intent services (for each side , server and client) and i didn't work. When i run it returns an error saying that the address is already in use. Maybe that can be solved, but i think that at this point, making a Service with 2 threads inside is easier.